# What are some simple video editor with Masking capability?

Tags: video, effects, video-editor, freeware

I want to focus faces of an image and move that focus to each of the faces one by one with a delay.The other area of the image should be hidden/blurred

(btw this is called masking right?).

Is there any simple opensource(or just free) software for doing this?

A trial version would do because I need to make only one urgent video for now.

A good tutorial would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oldie question, but let's add an answer...

The answer depends on if the faces are moving through the frame.

If the faces are relative still, like a camera on a tripod and the persons sitting in front of the camera, any video editor with more than 1 video channel can do the trick. Just add a layer with something on it, a prepared semi-transparent PNG as a mask perhaps.

But more complex software is needed if the faces are moving or if you want a blur, instead of a semi-transparent mask.

If the faces are moving you need to track them, so the program needs to track it.

As @Shultc commented Both Blender and HitFilm can do this, and I would add Davinci Resolve.

Comment: Do Blender and HitFilm track faces, for instance?

Comment: All 3 can track stuff, I do not know if there is a specific feature to recognize faces and then track them.

Answer (score 0):

- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) — Made for 3D, but can do video manipulations too. (open source, really hard)
- [HitFilm](https://hitfilm.com/) — Made for video. (have free version, easear)

Comment: natron is another option http://natron.fr/

Answer (score 0):

Since you state a trial version will do,  Adobe CC Premiere Pro fits the bill.  It's full featured and affordable after the trial license ends.